# Microsoft Excel Function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have air pollution measurements taken every second and I am looking to find a way to achieve the following:

- Find the median of every 9th, 10th, and 11th value for my whole dataset

It is a bit hard for me to describe but what I mean is I want to find the median value of the 9th, 10th, and 11th values, the median value of the 19th, 20th, and 21st values, the median value of the 29th, 30th, 31st values, and so on for my entire dataset. I'm looking for a function to complete this calculation as my dataset has about 8,000 rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX to return an array of the three numbers to MEDIAN:

```
=MEDIAN(INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},(ROW(A1)-1)*10+{9,10,11}))))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Put that in the first cell and copy down.  Each row will iterate to the next grouping.  First it will return 9,10,11 then 19,20,21 and so on.

[image]

---

The array function can be avoided if one wants to write out the three returns long hand:

```
=MEDIAN(INDEX(A:A,(ROW(A1)-1)*10+9),INDEX(A:A,(ROW(A1)-1)*10+10),INDEX(A:A,(ROW(A1)-1)*10+11))
```

this gets entered normally.

Comment: Since the three cells are sequential, they could be referenced by two INDEX functions; e.g. `=MEDIAN(INDEX(A:A, (ROW(1:1)-1)*10+9):INDEX(A:A, (ROW(1:1)-1)*10+11))` (tbh, I really don't get what the `IF({1}` was doing)

Comment: With older versions of Excel it was required to force an array. Otherwise only the first number was passed on. Dynamic array makes it unnecessary.   But you are correct on the joint range.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: @ScottCraner,, I've tried both of your formula but only get Median of 9 to 11 rest returns #NUM error. I'm using Excel 2013 & 2016. (used same set of data) !! [Check this link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ye6tff25wzkc086t0dlue/Test.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=s63iit1lp2f9qhk8ywfhpf7m5) or [Even](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlemq7va8vcfy1n/Test.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: @RajeshS you need to put more numbers in Column A.  Mine went down to 1200 rows.  You are getting the `#NUM` error because the INDEX is returning blanks and the median can't find the median of three blanks. rows 39 and beyond are blanks so the forth is basically doing: `=MEDIAN("","","")`

Comment: @ScottCraner,, okay I got the issue,,, and if I adjust the range like `A1:A50` instead of entire `column A`,  it works also. Thanks ☺